# Producing bar chart of a vector using qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have vectors as follows:

```
x = c(1:10)
y = c(1, 8, 87, 43, 67, 22, 99, 14, 75, 56)
```

I would like to produce a bar chart where the x-axis is just labeled 1-10, and the y-axis is the height of each value in the y-vector above. I have tried several commands similar to this one:

```
qplot(x, y, geom= "bar")
```

This leads to an error

```
Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
```

So, I tried two of the suggestions in this message. First:

```
qplot(x, stat="bin", geom= "bar")
```

But this lead to a chart where all 10 bars were of height one. Second:

```
qplot(x, stat="identity", geom= "bar")
```

But this lead to an error: Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing

As a side question, I would like to make each bar a different (or at least random color). Is this something straightforward to accomplish?

Comment: Here is a link to the online documentation with examples and code. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
qplot(x, y, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

`geom="bar"` is tricky because by default it wants to bin stuff.  If you provide a `y` value, then you have to tell it not to apply a statistic to the data.  This is what `stat="identity"` does.  Identity basically means "don't do anything".  If you do do this, then you have to specify a `y` value (this is what you're missing in your final example).  To add colors, you could:

```
qplot(x, y, geom="bar", stat="identity", fill=as.factor(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

any reason to use `qplot`? ggplot gives more flexibility, although not needed in this simple case.

```
x = c(1:10)
y = c(1, 8, 87, 43, 67, 22, 99, 14, 75, 56)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = as.factor(x))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `qplot` with the `stat` argument is deprecated. To use an existing quantity for the length of the bars use the `weight` argument:

`qplot(x, weight = y, geom = "bar")`

This will give you the usual "count" y-axis label.

However, the clearest approach for this type of data is to use the `col` geom instead of `bar`, as `col` expects a `y` argument to denote the lengths of the bars/columns:

`qplot(x, y, geom = "col")`

This will give you a y-axis label using your variable name, instead of "count".